# any(object.class) throwing null in mockito

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, powermock

I have the following class:

```
mockStatic(Exception.class); 

PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Exception.class);

Exception.throwErrorIfExists(any(Object.class)); // line3
```

In exception class,method is defined as follows:

```
static void throwErrorIfExists(def model){

  if(model.hasErrors())
    throwError(model)
  }
```

The following exception is thrown at line 3: `Cannot invoke method hasErrors() on null object
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method hasErrors() on null object`

How can `any(object.class)` be NULL in any circumstances because any simply means return any anything?

Comment: Out of interest, do you really have a class called `def`?

Comment: I am using groovy here,so def is defined by groovy itself

Comment: Ah, I see. I've not used groovy so I didn't recognise that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't invoke ThrowErrorIfExists with a null parameter, as you invoke a method (hasErrors() on it. This has nothing to do with any mocking, but it is just an error in your method.

You use a matcher to call the method

```
Exception.throwErrorIfExists(any(Object.class));
```

which is quite strange; matchers are used to configure the behaviour of a mock like

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Exception.throwErrorIfExists(any(Object.class)));
```

Then you can call throwErrorIfExists with any object to trigger the "do nothing".

Comment: this solution does not seems to work for me,the error is still the same.any(object.class) is taken as null

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misusing the [`any()`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any%28java.lang.Class%29) method. This method exists so that you can verify interactions with mocks, e.g. you can say:

```
// checks yourMethod() was invoked with any argument
verify(mockedObject).yourMethod(any(SomeClass.class));
```

If you want to call your method with some arbitrary object, you should create the object in your test and pass it in. `any()` is not a method that just makes objects for you.